# Raspberry Pi POCSAG mail script

Tags: linux, bash, script

I have a Raspberry Pi configured as a `Pocsag` receiver with a RTL-SDR USB stick.
Everything works just perfect, and it receives signals and messages.
I then found a script that was supposed to be able to grab certain `Pocsag` messages and send them as mail.
But the script throws an error:

```
/ricmail.sh: line 18: [: too many arguments
```

And the script looks like this:

```
!/bin/bash

# Add ricnumber.
riclist=(
’428824’
’408888’
)

while IFS=” read -r line

do

printf -v filename ”rtj`date +%Y_%m_%d`.log”
echo ”`date +%T` $line” >> $filename
count=0
while [ ”${riclist[count]}” != ”” ]
do
if [ ”${line/${riclist[count]}}” != ”$line” ] ; then # if $line minus first apperence of $riclist is diffrent from $line
echo $line | mail -s ”Pocsag Mail” email@host.com
fi
count=$(( $count + 1 ))
done

done
```

And I cant figure out the problem, anyone got any pointers?

Comment: What is POCSAG? Is it made for Raspberry Pi? Does it only run on a Raspberry Pi? What makes your question specific to Raspberry Pi, except that it is only running on it?

Comment: This question isn't Pi related which is why it will get closed. If you don't get an answer by then try asking in the Unix Stack Exchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix all those wonky quote marks in your code.

When I recoded your program as

```
#!/bin/bash

# Add ricnumber.
riclist=(
'428824'
'408888'
)

while IFS='' read -r line

do

    printf -v filename "rtj`date +%Y_%m_%d`.log"
    echo "`date +%T` $line" >> $filename
    count=0
    while [ "${riclist[count]}" != "" ]
    do
        if [ "${line/${riclist[count]}}" != "$line" ] ; then # if $line minus first apperence of $riclist is diffrent from $line
            echo $line | mail -s "Pocsag Mail" email@host.com
        fi
        count=$(( $count + 1 ))
    done

done
```

It runs OK and I get a rejected email because email@host.com doesn't exist.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! 
No idea how those quote marks came about, but it solved my issues :-)